# Proxying Traffic from Android with iptables

Tags: iptables, proxy, tcpdump, android

I have a Android device, and I'm trying to redirect HTTPS traffic to another host on my local network.

I've tried defining the proxy in the device network configuration, which works for everything except traffic originating from one specific package that I need visibility into. I've determined this by running tcpdump when invoking the app, and notice the below capture snippet.

```
... IP 192.168.1.4.38000 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [.] ...
... IP 1.2.3.4.443: > 192.168.1.4.38000 Flags [.] ...
```

My theory is that the app is probably proxy oblivious, so I proceed to set an outbound rule via iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4:8080
```

My expectation is that all outbound network traffic on port 443 should be redirected to the my proxy server, but I'm still seeing it go to `1.2.3.4:443` when running tcpdump. What could i be missing?

Comment: at first I don't see here a business environment relationship. at second why not use the opposite of and do it there? it just need to intercept the traffic and the device just needs the  certificate. I mean I have a firewall where I can reroute any traffic?